# GoLang parsing time.Now() sans timezone?

Tags: javascript, time, go, timezone

I have the following code in a program and the goal is to make sure an item is accessible within a timeframe. For some reason, this is coming in as false. I've logged the start, end, and now times.The start/end dates are coming in through a JSON request, with no timezone. The time.Now() is giving a timezone. Is that where I'm having my issue? How would I fix it?

```
func withinStartAndEnd(item Item) bool {
    fmt.Println("Start Date", item.Start_date, "\n")
    fmt.Println("End Date", item.End_date, "\n")
    fmt.Println("Now:", time.Now(), "\n")

    //BUG: For some reason event 0's are still not accessible within the timeframe. The fmt's above are to help look at it. time.Now() is printing MST.. maybe that's it?

    /*

    Start Date 2016-02-19 09:50:00 +0000 +0000
    End Date 2016-02-19 10:00:00 +0000 +0000
    Now: 2016-02-19 09:59:48.73003196 -0700 MST

    2016/02/19 09:59:48 Item not accessible (#148)

     */
    return item.Start_date.Before(time.Now()) && item.End_date.After(time.Now())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there really is no time zone, then use UTC, the [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
now := time.Now().UTC()
```

---

The goal is to get everything to UTC time. Perhaps, since DB time is actually MST,

```
// database time zone is Mountain Time
dbt, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Denver")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

now := time.Now().UTC()
start := item.Start_date.In(dbt).UTC()
end := item.End_date.In(dbt).UTC()
```

Comment: Hmm. It looks like the start/end dates are stored from the DB with no timezone, and date.now assumes no timezone = UTC, which compares the time.Now() that is MST. If I change time.Now to time.Now().MST(), it's several hours off of what the DB is. Maybe it's best to compare the dates, hours and seconds and ignore the timezone?

Comment: @NathanHyland: A specific time has to have a location. If you don't know the location, assuming UTC is best you can do.

Comment: Is there any way I can tell Go that the times pulled from the DB are MST, then? Or do I need to change the DB Type to have a date with timezone?

To clarify, not change the DB times TO MST (offsetting them a few hours from the UTC time that Go thinks it is), but change it directly to MST without affecting the time.

Comment: @NathanHyland: See my use of the `time` `In` method in my example to force database dates to Mountain Time. What happens if you use my example for nomalizing to UTC?

Comment: If I normalize to .UTC(), it will set my local time back however many hours. Before normalization, it compares 10:30 UTC (database) to 10:30 MST (Go). If I say time.Now().UTC(), it changes to 5:30PM UTC. I'd imagine the time.in would do the same thing if I try to convert the database UTC times to MST - it would just offset them the hours, it looks like (from the docs).

Comment: Printing those out gives me this (in now/start/end order) 
2016-02-19 18:11:49.469250213 +0000 UTC ||
 2016-02-19 10:45:00 +0000 UTC  ||
 2016-02-19 10:47:00 +0000 UTC ||